# I have tried to connect mongodb with my server. But the following error shows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, server

```
ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at run (C:\Users\DELOWAR\Desktop\Assignment 11\inventory-management-server\index.js:21:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELOWAR\Desktop\Assignment 11\inventory-management-server\index.js:38:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: Can you show codes of index.js file ? There is something wrong in that file.

Comment: Please use the stackoverflow format for questions. It needs some details in the description.

Answer (score 0):

1. First console the Uri
2. const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
   serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,